# how to delete particular statements of the entire workspace in Eclipse IDE using line numbers automatically

Tags: java, eclipse, file

Assume that i have been given information regarding all the Java Class names and particular line numbers in each particular .java file. Now i have to delete all the mentioned line numbers from each particular .java file automatically from the entire Eclipse Workspace.
How to do it?

Comment: Basically i have to automate the above said process

Answer (score 1):

You could dig into writing an eclipse plugin.

However, I guess you don't have 100's of projects scattered randomly over your hard disk.
So I'd just write a small standalone java program which reads the file names and line numbers, opens the respective files, deletes the lines and saves the files.

Comment: We have 1000's of .java files. Impossible to read all those files in a java program. Any other better solution?

Comment: @user3728785: No, it's not impossible.  Open file 1, delete lines, close file 1.  Open file 2, delete lines, close file 2.  Repeat thousands of times.